# can .net windows forms project and .net UWP project be merged?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I have a GUI windows form app written in .NET .

And I have a new .NET UWP app that has UWP camera and UWP sockets.

Can I port the UWP camera and UWP sockets code into the .NET Windows form app project?

(If I went the other way, it probably will take much longer to port the Windows forms GUI into a UWP GUI.)

Answer (score 1):

WinForm project can use most new Windows 10 API designed for UWP. Check [this post](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/01/25/calling-windows-10-apis-desktop-application/).

If went the other way, you need to port bit by bit of the existing GUI, so it all depends how complex your WinForm GUI is.

The first challenge is you are using XAML, another language instead of C# to write UWP UI.

Some WinForm controls you are using just do not have a UWP counterpart, you need to turn to the community to check if there are alternatives that are freely available l, or purchase proprietary product, or write your own control.

Answer (score -2):

No. WinForm and UWP projects are very different. UWP are compiled to native code and WinForm are compiled to IL that are then run by the CLR. Microsoft is currently working on the ability to put a UWP control inside a WinForm application. You can check it out [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xaml-platform/xaml-host-controls).